# DateTime: get next monday OR wednesday

Tags: php

Let's say I have a date and want to get the next monday OR wednesday, which was more closer from the date.

```
$date = 20211002;
$date_object = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', $date);
$next = $date_object->modify('next wednesday')->format('d/m/Y');
```

Is possible to set two or more weekdays?

Comment: What do you mean by _Is possible to set two or more weekdays?_ precisely?

Comment: Just try both of them in turn.

Comment: Just compare both of them ?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly you want to get the closest next Monday, or next Wednesday, to the given date. Since the Monday always precedes the Wednesday it will always be the Monday that is closer.

Comment: @nice_dev I want more use something like this: `next monday wednesday`, but only the last weekday is consired by the method.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware but if `$date` is a Tuesday, the method must return the next Wednesday.

Comment: Yes, you're right, my mistake. Can't you use that fact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but you can work around the issue:

```
// Closest "next" based on weekday ($date_object->format('w'))
// which is 0 (for Sunday) through 6 (for Saturday)
// 0 => monday    (from sunday)
// 1 => wednesday (from monday)
// 2 => wednesday (from tuesday)
// 3 => monday    (from wednesday)
// 4,5,6 => monday
```

So the next day is next wednesday only if format('w') is 1 or 2.

Therefore,

```
$go   = in_array(
    $date_object->format('w'),
    [ 1, 2 ]
) ? 'next wednesday' : 'next monday';
$next = $date_object->modify($go)->format('d/m/Y');
```